# breezejs hasChangesChanged event not raised

Tags: angularjs, breeze

Not quite sure if this is an AngularJS or BreezJs issue here...

I have a controller in which I do the following:

```
$scope.mandat = domiciliationService.createMandat();
```

and in the domiciliationService:

```
function createMandat () {
        return manager.createEntity('Mandate');
}
```

My View is bound to the $scope.mandat and when I change a value in a textbox bound to one of the properties of $scope.mandat, I can see it being reflected on the actual object (by displaying the value in a span). So far so good.

However, the hasChangesChanged event is never raised. In the service, here's how I've subscribed:

```
manager.hasChangesChanged.subscribe(function (args) {
        var hasChangesChanged = args.hasChanges;
        var entityManager = args.entityManager;
        alert('changed');
    });
```

It's like when I change values in the View, they modify the object on the $scope but not the actual Entity... What am I missing ?

Comment: First of all you are missing a live code example, perhaps with http://plnkr.co/.

Comment: it's difficult to put together a fiddle with breeze, I would need a webservice to return the metadata. What don't you understand in the above code ? I could explain in more details.

Comment: @sam - I have a plunker that you can fork. It reaches to the Todo sample which should be sufficient for you to demonstrate the problem.   pkozlowski - we'll soon offer a suite of plunkers and jsFiddles to help people get started. I agree that this is by far the best way for people to clarify and repro issues.

Comment: any chance you can provide me with the link ? :)

Comment: @Sam - I was unable to reproduce problem.The hasChangesChanged event is actually raised. Try downloading the samples (http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/packages/breeze-runtime-plus-1.3.0.zip) and, in the Todo-Angular sample, subscribe to hasChangesChanged. You will see that it is raised each time you change a property (text or check box).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after playing a bit with this event, I've figured out two things. Actually to make sure that my code was not the problem, I've debugged the John Papa's Hot Towel application as he uses breeze too. And the behavior is the same as in my app.

1. When I create a new entity, the hasChangesChanged event is fired. Then when I enter data in the form's controls that are bound to the properties of this entity, the event is not fired.
2. When I edit an existing entity, then the hasChangesChanged event is only fired when I modifify a property (if I edit value in a textbox).

So, one could argue that the hasChangesChanged event should not be triggered in the first scenario until user starts to actually filling in data. But I can live with that.

Comment: hasChangesChanged is triggered only after an entity has changed entityState to requiring a save - if an added entity has a property changed, the requirement to save has not changed, but an existing entity having the first property changed does require save. For more granularity see entityChanged event